# Timescale of nuclear interaction

Tags: nuclear-physics

Can the timescales of nuclear interaction processes, like inelastic scattering or transfer reactions be found out?

Comment: We can estimate the lifetimes of intermediate states from the line widths. Is this the sort of thing you're asking about?

Comment: No. I was asking about interaction timescale, as in, the time frame in which the interaction takes place when two nuclei are within few fm of each other. For instance, during inelastic scattering, is there any defined timescale for the projectile to excite the target, when they are within the range of the interaction? First of all this range will have to be estimated.

Comment: Well that is pretty much the timescale of the intermediate state. I can't see what other timescales are involved.

Comment: The field of "attosecond physics" might be of some interest to you in this matter: the time is assigned from a naive calculation of the flyby time for a relativistic ion passing an atom. A similar naive calculation with nuclei is very easy.

Comment: I'll look into it. What I am mainly interested in is the collision timescale.